# Creating a pandas dataframe out of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary `data` which has a structure like so:

```
{
    1: {
        'title': 'Test x Miss LaFamilia - All Mine [Music Video] | Link Up TV',
        'time': '2020-06-28T18:30:06Z',
        'channel': 'Link Up TV',
        'description': 'SUB & ENABLE NOTIFICATIONS for more:  Visit our clothing store:  Visit our website for the latest videos: ...',
        'url': 'youtube',
        'region_searched': 'US',
        'time_searched': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 6, 13, 6, 5, 188727, tzinfo = < UTC > )
    },
    2: {
        'title': 'Day 1 Highlights | England Frustrated by Rain as Babar Impresses | England v Pakistan 1st Test 2020',
        'time': '2020-08-05T18:29:43Z',
        'channel': 'England & Wales Cricket Board',
        'description': 'Watch match highlights of Day 1 from the 1st Test between England and Pakistan at Old Trafford. Find out more at ecb.co.uk This is the official channel of the ...',
        'url': 'youtube',
        'region_searched': 'US',
        'time_searched': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 6, 13, 6, 5, 188750, tzinfo = < UTC > )
    }
```

I am trying to make a pandas DataFrame which would look like this:

```
rank    title                             time                      channel             description                                     url                             region_searched         time_searched
1       Test x Miss LaFamilia...          2020-06-28T18:30:06Z      Link Up TV          SUB & ENABLE NOTIFICATIONS for more...          youtube.com                     US                      2020-8-6 13:06:05
2       Day 1 Highlights | E...           2020-08-05T18:29:43       England & ..        Watch match highlights of D                     youtube.com                     US                      2020-8-6 13:06:05
```

In my `data` dictionary, each `key` should be `rank` entry in my `DataFrame`, and each `key` inside the parent `key` is an entry which column name is the `key` and their value is the `value` that `key` holds.

When I simply run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The df looks like this:

```
                 1                                                  2
title            Test x Miss LaFamilia - All Mine [Music Video]...  Day 1 Highlights | England Frustrated by Rain ...
time             2020-06-28T18:30:06Z                               2020-08-05T18:29:43Z
channel          Link Up TV                                         England & Wales Cricket Board
description      SUB & ENABLE NOTIFICATIONS for more: http://go...  Watch match highlights of Day 1 from the 1st T...
url              youtube.com/watch?v=YB3xASruJHE                    youtube.com/watch?v=xABoyLxWc7c
region_searched  US                                                 US
time_searched    2020-08-06                                         2020-08-06
```

Which I feel like is few smart pivot lines away from what I need but I can't figure out how can I achieve the structure I need in a smart way.

Comment: after you create your df, try `df.T` to transpose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data.values()).assign(rank = data.keys())
```

---

```
                                               title  ... rank
0  Test x Miss LaFamilia - All Mine [Music Video]...  ...    1
1  Day 1 Highlights | England Frustrated by Rain ...  ...    2
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in a much simpler way as [@dm2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13590089/dm2) mentioned in the comments. Here `d` is the dictionary which has the data

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
dfz=df.T
```

To create the `rank` column

```
dfz['rank']=dfz.index
```

Comment: Oh yeah, pandas Transpose would fit this issue nicely

Answer (score 1):

**If you want index and rank to be two different columns**

1. Create a dataframe from the data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data.values())
```

2. Just add a rank column in the dataframe

```py
df['rank'] = data.keys()
```

OR

To do this in one line use `assign` method

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data.values()).assign(rank = data.keys())
```

**If you want index and rank to be same column**

1. Create the dataframe but in transpose order

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

2. Rename the index

```py
df.index.names = ['rank']
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping trough the dict keys and appending to a new df for each value. (replace the object "dict" to your variable)

```
df_full = pd.DataFrame()
for key in dict.keys():
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(dict[key])
    df_full = pd.concat([df_full, df_temp], axis=0)
```